# Parallel Testing with MBUnit/Gallio using Data Driven Test Cases

Tags: selenium, webdriver, mbunit, selenium-grid, parallel-testing

I've been doing a lot of reading up on `RemoteWebDriver` for Selenium 2 using Selenium Grid. At the moment my tests are generated in the `Test()` using the `[Test]` Attribute.

I have a `TestCriteria` class that I fill with information and then use the Selenium WebDriver 'Page Object Design Pattern' as a way of 'controlling' how this data is entered into my tests.

So, I have a simple criteria object, for example:

```cs
public class Credentials
{ 
    public string Username { get; set; } 
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then use this information in a LoginPage object.

```cs
public class LoginPage
{
    [FindsByAnnotation]
    public IWebElement UsernameField { get; set; }

    [FindsByAnnotation]
    public IWebelement PasswordField { get; set; }

    [FindsByAnnotation]
    public IWebelement SubmitButton { get; set; }

    public HomePage Login(Credentials cred)
    {
         UsernameField.SendKeys(cred.user);
         // code for login and return new HomePage object
    }
}
```

Now, with this sort of structure I am able to create some good method chaining in my Tests once I have the test data, things like my Credentials object, Data that needs to be filled in on other pages etc.

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture
{
     private IWebDriver driver;
     private TestCaseData data; // Which contains a Credentials object etc etc

     [SetUp]
     public void SetUp()
     {
         data = new TestCaseData() 
         { 
              Credentials = new Credentials() 
              { 
                   Username = "username", 
                   Password = "password"
              }
             // Other test case data objects can be populated here 
         };

         driver = new FireFoxDriver();
     }

     [Test]
     public void Test()
     {
          new LoginPage().Login(data.Credentials)
                         .NavigateToSearchPage()
                         .EnterSearchCriteria(data.SearchCritiera)
          // etc
     }
```

}

This is all well and good, but...what If i wanted to LOAD in this test data from a serialised TestData object which can be deserialised from XML.

I'm also interested in using `RemoteWebDriver`, which I have already used however is still flakey compared to using just `IWebDriver driver = new FireFoxDriver();` , however ignoring these matters, I would really like to run a TESTCASE more than once...at the same time. Which brings me to the question of parallel testing.

I understand MBUnit can handle this which is part of Gallio, I had also looked into PUnit which is an extension of Nunit but it still has a long way to come. So I have decided to stick with MbUnit.

This gives me the ability to run the TestFixtures with the attribute `[Parallelizable]`.  So if I compile my project and load in the project dll into Gallio TestRunner GUI I can run 4 test cases at the same time, which in return opens up 4 browsers running each test at the same time, also giving the ability to stress the site while all 4 tests are running. (obviously this would be increased to run several hundred browsers on multiple machines using selenium RemoteWebDriver with Selenium Grid.

Does anyone here know a way where I can load in a collection of xml serialised objects, GENERATE new TestFixture objects which can have the `[Parallelizable]` attribute added to the top of the test fixture and have them all run at the same time after loading in 1 - 10 .xml files from a, for example: C:\TestCase directory?

My idea is to have these all loaded in, and then have Selenium Grid handle the browser sessions with 1 - 5 Selenium nodes running connected to the main selenium grid hub.

I am just having a difficulty really taking advantage of Selenium Grid when I can not find a framework which allows me to generate a `Test Fixture`, which includes a `[SetUp]` `[TearDown]` `[Test]` and the ability to set certain test conditions to Test Attributes depending on what is loaded from the TestCase .xml file.

For example if a TestCase .xml file had an element which was fail then how can I load this .xml file in and set an attribute on my TestFixture's [Test] for this, or map the TestCase .xml Description of test to the `[Test(Description = "")]` attribute at run time.

I already know the functionality of selenium webdriver, the page object design pattern, the selenium `EventFiringWebDriver` functionality for screenshots.

How can i utilize the ability to load in several XML serialised TestCaseData, generate new TestFixture objects after these have been loaded?

Ideally I would like the [SetUp] of each TestFixture to setup the `IWebDriver` because certain URLs would be different depending on what the TestCase.xml file would contain, for example of this test is to run on a UAT environment, Test environment, Pre-Production environment, I need to set this up before the test is run.

Does anyone have a basic example which uses these main concepts with Selenium Grid/Selenium WebDriver with the ability to run these Test Fixtures in parallel to utilise Selenium Grid functionality of running multiple browsers.

So something I am looking for in pseudo code.

```cs
public class Main()
{
   // Load Testfixtures
   List<TestCase> testCases = Deserialise("\\Some\\FolderLocation");

   foreach(test in testCases)
   { 
      // create NEW testFixture, not [Test]
      // ability to attach parallel TestFixture
   }  
}

[Testfixture]
[Parallelizable]
public class TestFixture
{

     public TestCase testCase { get; set; }
     public IWebDriver driver { get; set; }

     [SetUp]
     public void SetUp()
     {
         if(testCase.Environment == "UAT")
         {
             driver = new FireFoxDrive()
             driver.NavigateTo("http://localhost/uat/Login");
         }

         // What if the testCase.ShouldPass is false?

         // How can i generate my [Test] with ExpectedException?

     }

      [Test]
      public void Test()
      {
          // code here with page object method chaining passing in testCase data objects  
      }
}
```

Maybe I am going about this design the wrong way. Any suggestions please on the best way to parallelize these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```cs
public class TestCase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static class TestCaseFactory
{
    public static IEnumerable<TestCase> TestCases()
    {
        yield return new TestCase { Name = "one" };
        yield return new TestCase { Name = "two" };
    }
}

[Factory(typeof(TestCaseFactory), "TestCases"), Parallelizable]
public class DataDrivenFixture
{
    private readonly TestCase testCase;

    public DataDrivenFixture(TestCase testCase)
    {
        this.testCase = testCase;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SetUp " + testCase.Name);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test " + testCase.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I eventually found this one out, its fantastic, I found pretty much the same with Nunit TestCaseSource. Thanks :) +1

Answer (score 0):

good solution.
but what about run tests in parallel different browsers?
if I initialize IWebDriver in [FixtureSetUp] then browsers opened and run tests but with errors (basicly NoSuchElement).

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCase> TestCases()
        {
            yield return new TestCase { Name = "internet explorer" };
            yield return new TestCase { Name = "firefox" };
        }

[FixtureSetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SetUp " + testCase.Name);
            switch (testCase.Name)
            {
                case "internet explorer":
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    break;
                case "chrome":
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                case "firefox":
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to run tests in parallel, you'll have to make full use of the selenium GRID. this way the selenium grid can keep track of sessions and which browsers it should be sending requests to.

Comment: I try running on Grid and without it. It doesn't matter, tests fails with nosuchelement. I think that because of Webdriver doesn't thread-safe. But i don't know how to make WebDriver safe-thread or another way to use it with different browsers at same time.

Comment: The point is to use RemoteWebDriver, it doesn't need to be thread safe as you are not running the same RemoteWebDriver twice, you create two instances of RemoteWebDriver which connect to the SAME Selenium Grid 2 Server. This will handle the browsers for you. 

If you showed me some more code It may be easier to understand what you are having trouble with.

Have you looked into using the TPL? This provides you with ways to execute tasks in parallel. You could use this as a way to create two RemoteWebDriver instances in the same [Test]. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

Comment: Take a look at http://nuget.org/packages/Saucery2 and http://nuget.org/packages/Saucery3.  These are for NUnit2 and NUnit3.  Gallio MbUnit appears to have this issue still (v3.4.14).  NUnit 3.2 will have parallel testing within a testfixture.  The beta already supports parallel tests across test fixtures